# How to movie particular user in top by default

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a table with this structure,

**Topic**

1. UserID
2. TopicID

**Roles**

1. Admin
2. Users

**UserInROles**
userID
RoleID

[image]

My Requirement,

**By default (admin role) topicid should show always in the top .**

Note :  There will be only one admin.

**Admin Userid : 10**

wherever i am executing the query,i need to get admin topic should be On the top

This was i am trying to get result

[image]

Sagar For your answer,(but check my result how i am expecting)
[image]

Comment: You mean you have two tables, Topic and Roles?

Comment: Please tag the correct rdbms.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @jarlh yes..  "userInroles"

Comment: yes.. but there will be single admin for the topic... no more than that

Comment: schema of Roles table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--This will help you

```
select * 
from tblTable 
order by (case id when 10 then 0 else 1 end), dbo.id desc
```

Comment: this will not work,"Result wil be showing based on the userid".. see the attached image, with the expected result

Comment: i tried... result is : 10 5
10 3
10 15
10 8
10 47
21 50
21 20
21 23
21 30
21 2
11 12
11 13
11 16
8 10
8 74
8 21
2 4

Comment: please share whole query